# SQLLite Copy table contents with identical schema

Tags: sqlite

I have two SQL Lite tables with identical schema/structure.

Just rows are different.

I want to copy all rows from srcTable that are not already in destTable. The index may be different! But that should not matter for the copy operation.

I need a quick and easy way, as the table has really many columns.

My srctable has a little bit a weird name, it is called:

```
importing_nowtelco_08989.csv
```

Is it a problem that the name contains a .?

The program I use to execute the SQL is called DB Browser for SQLite

I have used numerous operations and even complicated ones like

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT A,B,C,D,E
FROM srcTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM destTable 
WHERE (
                       srcTable.A=destTable.A and
                       srcTable.B=destTable.B and
                       srcTable.C=destTable.C and
                       srcTable.D=destTable.D and
                       srcTable.E=destTable.E 
                       ))
```

and

```
SELECT * INTO destTable FROM srcTable

SELECT A,B,C,D,E INTO destTable FROM srcTable
```

but nothing worked

Comment: You must enclose the table's name inside backticks or square brackets.

Comment: Are there any other columns than A,B,C,D,E in destTable?

Answer (score 0):

Your code would fail if the columns `A, B, C, D and E` may contain `null`s because any comparison to `null` with the operator `=` returns `null`.
I would suggest:

```
INSERT INTO destTable(A, B, C, D, E)
SELECT A, B, C, D, E FROM srcTable
EXCEPT
SELECT A, B, C, D, E FROM destTable
```

It's a good practice to include `destTable`'s columns in the INSERT statement.
Also enclose `importing_nowtelco_08989.csv` inside backticks or square brackets.

Comment: so this works if the rows are exactly identical contents, eg. the combination of A, B, C, D, E is identical?

Comment: Yes, this is what EXCEPT does.

Comment: the problem is my table is called import.csv Is this a problem, because it says it cannot find the table

Comment: Use this: `[import.csv]` for tablename.